# Luajit table overflow error when loading cdefs using ffi.cdef

Tags: ffi, luajit

I am using Luajit to load multiple libraries one at a time. After loading a library I load its corresponding cdefs also. But I see error 'table overflow' in the log after I load the 2 or 3 libraries.
I know the size of each cdef is huge. Is there any limitation to the size of cdefs we can load. 
Can we increase the size? Any other alternate workaround to this problem ?
Can we forcibly clear the cdefs loaded?

Comment: _how_ big are your cdefs? I've successfully used cdefs including the entire OpenGL 4.4 specification with no issues, even alongside other massive libraries.

Comment: Each file is approx 3MB size.For single file it works but it fails when I do ffi.cdef on second one. each file contains approx 1000000+ lines

Comment: Those sound exceptionally big; I feel like Lua strings of that size in general probably have issues. Can you break the cdefs apart to have a few smaller ones? Additionally, you might want to collect garbage after each cdef to clear out the huge string.

Comment: I think all the cdef are stored in same table, so if we break it into smaller chunks also it would complain. And I dont think we can garbage collect the cdef. It stays as long as the program is running. Correct me if anything is incorrect here.

Comment: I have a made a Lua C-preprocessor tool for generating LuaJIT bindings from C headers.  When ffi.cdef'ing just a few standard C #include files I can reach this ffi.C table limit.  Anyone who thinks this is an unreasonable number of lines to feed ffi.cdef  probably doesnt realize how many lines a typical C include file has.